# Paging with << >> and Prev and Last and stop infinite paging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The output of this code is to create a page for every 8 divs.

```js
pageSize = 8;

showPage = function(page) {
  $('.line-content').hide();
  $('.line-content:gt('+((page-1)*pageSize)+'):lt('+(page)*(pageSize-1)+')').show();
   $('.line-content:eq('+((page-1)*pageSize)+')').show();
}

var pgs = Math.ceil($('.line-content').length/pageSize);
var pgnt = '';
  for(var i=1;i<=pgs;i++){
 pgnt += '<li><a href="#">'+i+'</a></li>';
}
$('#pagin').html(pgnt);
$("#pagin li a").click(function() {
  $("#pagin li a").removeClass("current");
 $(this).addClass("current");
 showPage(parseInt($(this).text())) 
});
showPage(1);
```

```css
.current {
  color: green;
}

#pagin li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="line-content">1 I have some content</div>
<div class="line-content">2 I have some content</div>
<div class="line-content">3 I have some content</div>
<div class="line-content">4 I have some content</div>
<div class="line-content">5 I have some content</div>
<div class="line-content">6 I have some content</div>
<div class="line-content">7 I have some content</div>
<div class="line-content">8 I have some content</div>
<div class="line-content">9 I have some content</div>
<div class="line-content">10 I have some content</div>
<div class="line-content">11 I have some content</div>
<div class="line-content">12 I have some content</div>

<ul id="pagin"></ul>
```

The code will create `<li><a href></a></li>` tag for every 8 `<Div>` like a paging style. now here is my question. this code will create so many `<li><a href></a></li>` as long as it meets the condition which I dont want to happen. My concern here is this. how can I make a page that looks like this?

`<< Prev 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 Next >>`

I just wanted to create atleast 8 containers that will replace the page I i reach more than 8 are adjust its number of page if it less than 1. then add some `Prev` and `Next` and `<< >>`

TYSM for future help

Comment: The easiest way that comes to mind would be to hold the current page in a global variable and have "<< Prev" call `showPage(current_page - 1)`.

Comment: Sir Please How.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you are after but have a look at this:
(working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/whp1uhfo/ )

```
pageSize = 8;
current_page = 1;


var pgs = Math.ceil($('.line-content').length/pageSize);
var pgnt = '<li><span id="prev" onclick="showPage(current_page - 1)"> &lt;&lt; Prev</span>';

showPage = function(page) {
  $('.line-content').hide();
  $('.line-content:gt('+((page-1)*pageSize)+'):lt('+(page)*(pageSize-1)+')').show();
   $('.line-content:eq('+((page-1)*pageSize)+')').show();
   current_page = page;
   // if that's the last page, hide "Next"
   if(page == pgs){
       $('#next').hide();
   }else{
         $('#next').show();
   }
   // if that's the first page, hide "Prev"
   if(page == 1){
       $('#prev').hide();
   }else{
         $('#prev').show();
   }
}

for(var i=1;i<=pgs;i++){
    pgnt += '<li><a href="#">'+i+'</a> </li> ';
}

pgnt += '<li><span id="next" onclick="showPage(current_page + 1)">Next &gt;&gt;</span>';

$('#pagin').html(pgnt);
$("#pagin li a").click(function() {
  $("#pagin li a").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
    showPage(parseInt($(this).text())) 
});
showPage(1);
```

Comment: Upon checking your code it looks that the div is populating instead a steady 8 divs per page. anyways sir I hope we can talk tomorrow. TYSM :) on my way home.